# Identifying a certain common section on pages in a website

Tags: php, jquery

I have a list of common links for product pages, and I need to go through and grab all the links for the product image on each product page.

Eg I have got this far: I have a whole spreadsheet full of links like this

```
http://www.apc.com/products/moreimages.cfm?partnum=WSYSW100KF
```

the problem is I need the acutal image links for another column on my spreadsheet (it;s going to be used for a import on a eccomerce shop)

the thing is these image links don't seem to match up in any way and can be quite varied

```
http://www.apcmedia.com/resource/images/500/Front_Left/98EC66CA-5056-AE36-FE51936B432B1C17_pr.jpg
```

I have identified though that these images sit in what looks like a common area on the product page code

```
<div align="center"><img align="center" src="http://www.apcmedia.com/resource/images/500/Front_Left/98EC66CA-5056-AE36-FE51936B432B1C17_pr.jpg"></div>
```

How can I indetify that `<img align="center" src="">` part in Jquery on each page ?

I'm thinking if I iterate through all those links, then I can grab the releavnt direct Image link, grab it and repopulate into another spreadsheet column.

I'm just not 100% on how to achieve this, any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this selector to select the relevant images:

```
var result = [];
$("div[align=center] > img[align=center]").each(function(){
   var link = $(this).prop("src");
   //Do something, eg:
   result.push(link);
});
//result is a list which hold all links
```

`.prop()` returns the absolute URL of an image, even when the `src` attribute contains a relative URL. 
`A > B` selects every element `B` which is an immediate child of `A`.

If your src *attribute** follows a certain pattern, you can also use the following selector:

```
$("div[align=center] > img[src^='http://path/to/images'][src$='.jpg']");
//src^= means: Match if the `src` attribute starts with ...
//src$= means: Match if the `src` attribute ends with ...
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at that - the path to image (src attribute) is kind of regular, but it does seem to vary from time to time eg iut always has the path up to "images", but the folders after can sometime vary. http://www.apcmedia.com/resource/images/500/Front_Left/98EC66CA-5056-AE36-FE51936B432B1C17_pr.jpg